# Getting value from hex dump of Visual Studio test log

Tags: performance, testing, visual-studio-2012, load-testing

Visual Studio stores the testlog in LoadTestTestLog table of Loadtest2010 database. The test log value looks to be a hex dump. any pointers on how I could actually get data from it like context parameter name or other test related data?

I tried converting the dump into string readable format and it looks like the entire data is serialized in some manner.

[image: Snapshot of decode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that there is no public interface for decoding this data.

`.webtestresult` files can be decoded as shown [in this Microsoft blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/slumley/2009/11/11/vsts-2010-feature-api-for-processing-web-test-results/). However data extracted from the LoadTestTestLog table of the Loadtest2010 database is in a different format. Applying the code from the blog gives a de-serialisation error.

The data in this table can be viewed in Visual Studio. Results from previous load test results can be opened and viewed. See [this page](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/14503/6752) for more details. Having opened a load test the test case logs can be viewed, but only one at a time. To examine all the logs of a test run can entail lots of mouse movements and mouse clicks.

I have raised a [Visual Studio UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3894338-provide-a-way-of-exporting-or-converting-webtestre) issue on this topic. The November 14, 2013 comment wants the export of load test files. Please add your suggestions and/or votes to encourage Microsoft to do more in this area.

Comment: [sigh], I just revisited the UserVoice, only to find, sadly, it's now been brushed aside -- _"When a suggestion is archived, you ... can’t support them anymore. **Also Microsoft will not pay attention to these suggestions**"_.